# Validate/Preprocess property before assigning it to object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, object, javascript-objects

**What is the best-practice to validate and/or preprocess a property before assigning it to an object in JavaScript?**

The application for that would be to create an object and to guarantee that a specific property of it will always have a specific type or maybe do some preprocessing with it.

For example, if I create an object:

```
var obj = {
    settings: {}
};
```

Then when I do something like:

```
obj.settings = "{foo: bar}";
```

It would automatically check the type of the assignment - if it is a string, it will try to parse it to an object; if it's an object, it will just assign it; else it will throw an error. This would protect the object's property against being assigned to "anything".

Also, **does this make sense at all to do in JavaScript or am I just trying to have strong typed features in a language that is weak typed?**

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with [Object.defineProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty):

```
var obj = {}
Object.defineProperty(obj, 'settings', {
  set: function (x) {
    if (typeof x === 'string') {
      this._settings = JSON.parse(x)
    } else {
      this._settings = x
    }
  },
  get: function () {
    return this._settings
  }
})

obj.settings = {foo: 'bar'}
console.log(obj.settings)
obj.settings = '{foo: "baz"}'
console.log(obj.settings)
```

However, if this is desirable depends on your specific use case. I frankly never used it so far. My recommendation is: don't get fancy :)

IMHO this is not strong typing, but the opposite as you are more dynamic. If you want strong typing you could try [flow](https://flow.org/en/) or [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/)

Comment: A try-catch would be nice too for the `JSON.parse()` since this is prone to other issues and yours is a more detailed solution. (Surprised you beat me to answering it :) )

Comment: well, isn't throwing an exception exactly what you want in this case? else, invalid JSON would be silently "accepted" (to which value?).

Comment: Good point. Yes, indeed it should throw an error as required by the OP. I'm up-voting this response

Comment: This works fine for what I asked! I'm just not sure if it this approach is "ok" for JavaScript though. If you want to be consistent, you'd be creating getters/setters for every single property in an object to certify its properties data types. In that case, maybe it's better to use TypeScript, like you said. At least for the preprocessing case I think it is fine.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution could be to use a getter/setter like below that gets triggered if a value is assigned to a property and how to process it :

```
let obj = {}
Object.defineProperty(obj, "settings", {
 set: function (value) { // preprocess
    this._value = value;
 },
 get: function () {
    return "changed";
}
});
```

You could do this afterward:

```
    obj.settings = "{foo: bar}";
```

Let me know if this makes any sense.

Reference:
[MDN Reference: *Object.defineProperty()*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)

Comment: Yes, it makes sense! [lipp's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50698861/6381989) is closer to what I've imagined. So using ```Object.defineProperty()``` is probably the approach in this case.